# Embedded Structure with interface not working

Tags: go, struct, interface, radix

Below code not able to set or get the values from base entity

How to make it working to get base as well as inherited struct to return values

```
type BaseEntity struct {
    Id string
}

func (p BaseEntity) SetId(Id string) {
    p.Id = Id
}

func (p BaseEntity) GetId() string { 
    return p.Id
}

type Employee struct {
    BaseEntity
    Name string
}

type DataInterface interface {
    SetId(Id string)
    GetId() string  
}

func getObjFactory() DataInterface {
    //return Data.Employee{BaseEntity: Data.BaseEntity{}}
    return new(Employee)
}

func main() {   
    entity := getObjFactory()

    entity.SetId("TEST")
    fmt.Printf(">> %s", entity.GetId())     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `SetId` is using a value receiver so `p` is a copy of the object as opposed to a pointer to the object.

Instead, you want to use a pointer receiver as below:

```
func (p *BaseEntity) SetId(Id string) {
    p.Id = Id
}
```

You can find more details in the Tour of Go under section [Choosing a value or pointer receiver](https://tour.golang.org/methods/8).